# How to display Django reverse ForeignKey Data?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have 2 models, and I want to display data through my first model, suppose `Model1` have some fields and `Model2` have `ForeignKey` of `Model1`, and I am getting data through `Model1` on the display page, but I want to display some records from `Model2` also, Please let me know how I can display data from `Model2`.

here is my `models.py` file...

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    namefield=models.Charfield(blank=True)class Model1(models.Model):
    emailfield=models.Charfield(blank=True)
    phone=models.Charfield(blank=True)

class Model2(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(default=None)
    type=models.CharField(default=None)
    father=models.CharField(default=None)
    model1=models.Foreignkey(Model1, related_name='model_one', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

here is my `views.py` file...

```
def display_data(request, id):
    test_display = Model1.objects.filter(pk=id).first()
    context = {
        'test_display': test_display
    }
    return render(request, 'page.html', context)
```

please note I am displaying data here from `Model1`...but I want to display `name`, `type` and `father` from `Model2`

here is my `test.html` file...

```
<p>{{  test_display.namefield  }}</p>
<p>{{  test_display.emailfield  }}</p>
<p>{{  test_display.phone  }}</p>

<p>{{  test_display.model_one.name  }}</p>
<p>{{  test_display.model_one.type  }}</p>
<p>{{  test_display.model_one.father  }}</p>
```

`these last 3 records displaying nothing`

Answer (score 0):

In that models.py you had assumed foreign key in the wrong way.

Assume the Models like this

```
class Model1(models.Model):
         namefield=models.Charfield(blank=True)
         emailfield=models.Charfield(blank=True)
         phone=models.Charfield(blank=True)

class Model2(models.Model):
            name=models.Foreignkey(Model1.namefiled)
            type=models.CharField(default=None)
            father=models.CharField(default=None)
```

You want in reverse manner means

Put
`namefiled=models.ForiegnKey(Model1.name)'

Comment: I want to display `Model2` data through the above mention relation and views file

Comment: how can it possible?.see while counting the number you will start from 1,2,3 Nah. Not like in 2,3,1